# Height of images set as a background positioned absolute

Tags: html, css, image

I got a problem with height of images set as a background in rotation on my website. Is any way to scale my images when resolution is changing, without setting their height to rigid 300px, what cause on the smaller devices problem with free space under the image?

**HTML CODE**

```
       <li>

        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <div class="image-rotation"> 
        <img src="files/img_02.jpg" alt="Tytuł filmu i kategoria" /> 
        <img src="files/img_03.jpg" alt="Tytuł filmu i kategoria" /> 
        <img src="files/img_04.jpg" alt="Tytuł filmu i kategoria" /> 
        <img src="files/img_05.jpg" alt="Tytuł filmu i kategoria" /> 
        </div>

        <article class="img-hover">
            <div class="row text-vertical">
              <div class="small-12 columns small-centered">

                <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="small-6 columns small-centered">

                    <div class="row">

                      <dl class="small-4 columns text-center">
                        <dt><a href="#" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video">
                        <span class="icon-heart3"></span></a></dt>
                        <dd><span class="value">422</span></dd>
                        <dd><span class="name">likes</span></dd>
                      </dl>

                      <div class="small-4 columns text-center"><img src="img/sep.png" alt="" /></div>

                      <dl class="small-4 columns text-center">
                        <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>
                        <dd><span class="value">323</span></dd>
                        <dd><span class="name">views</span></dd>
                      </dl>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </li>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
<style>
.overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
background: url('../img/overlay.png');
}

.image-rotation {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
}

.image-rotation img {
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: none;
z-index: 4;
opacity: 1;
}

.img-hover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 11;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: url('../img/img-hover.png');
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .70s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .70s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .70s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

I was trying to use max-height for the image-rotation class, but then the height got 0px and images are not displayed. Please help me! Maybe someone of us got any JS solution to that problem?

Best regards,

Kuba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped someone out yesterday.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your head tags for starters.

In your CSS file:

```
/* Retina display */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Mobile HD */
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 760px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Mobile LD */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have considered doing it that way - by using @media, but I hoped there was more flexible way to this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can link up multiple CSS to your website with media queries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="mobile and (max-width: 600px)" href="different.css" />
```

This way you will load the normal CSS first, and alter other lines for mobile screens.
So you can add in any css you want to change on smaller resolutions in the other file.

You can also use CSS inline media queries if you want to use only one CSS file.

```
@media mobile and (min-width: 600px) {
  .image-rotation {
        //your code here
    }
}
```